# Purge Failed Deployments

Tags: deployment

Is there any way to purge failed deployments?  I've had to do a few from Eclipse ahead of a massive Inbound ChangeSet, and a few failures occurred in the process.  There's no particular reason other than my own OCD (I don't particularly want to look at a bunch of failures for the next 90 days) and that it freaks me out during deployments when I glance at the page and see failures, only to realize they are historical failures...

[image]

Comment: Can you include some sort of screenshot so it is more clear what you are talking about?

Comment: @AdrianLarson done

Comment: So this doesn't really have anything to do with Eclipse, since it seems you are looking to purge them from the UI.

Comment: Correct.  However, it has to do with Eclipse only because when it's from an Inbound Change Set, I can delete the Change Set and it'll purge the deployment record.  Since it's Eclipse, there's no Change Set for me to kill...

Comment: Maybe try `Database.delete(Id.valueOf('0AF0000006Wy1q'))`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I tried it out, got: System.TypeException: DML not allowed on DeployRequest

Comment: Well, looks like I'm stuck with them.  No harm, but thought I'd throw it out to the community to see what they came up with :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way we can delete the DeployRequest records in salesforce as Sys admins would want to keep track of everything being deployed into their Production ORG and for customer's to be SOX Compliant.(Though it can be tracked in Audit trail)

A funny solution to your problem would be to Validate a successful package 10 times, so that you will not see the failure records on the main deployment status page :)

Comment: Not true. Failures are displayed in a separate table above the successes. Adding ten successes will not effect the entries displayed in the failures table.